# Vue: ESlint rule to remove "this" from template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint

I am trying to see if there's an existing ESlint rule that would remove `this` used before props or data.

Example:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="this.foo"></div>
</template>
```

Ideally, this would get caught by the linter because of `this.foo` rather than just `foo`.  Does a rule for this exist? I tried searching the last few days but I had no luck finding one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`this`](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/this-in-template.html) (no pun intended) is what you are looking for. Though it won't explicitly 'remove' it, it will throw an error for you to review I believe.